# Best environment to practice Javascript

Tags: javascript, ide

I currently have Notepad++ and Aptana Studio. Is there any other development environment that eases the writing of javascript code ? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**IDEs**: [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/), [vim](http://www.vim.org/)

**Browser**: [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/), with the [Firebug extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/). The [Venkman debugger](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/javascript-debugger/) is also nice for serious debugging

**For practicing/testing**: http://jsfiddle.net/ - A great site where you can try out your JavaScript, share it with friends, etc.  Also useful for posting JS questions to SO.

Answer (score 6):

This programmer recommends firefox + firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may prove to be very useful:

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try editor + node.js. It is not inside a browser, but if you to learn JavaScript, not only DOM, node.js is a good choice too.